# Get arguments of Celery retry method in unit test

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, celery, django-celery

I have a Celery task that I call asynchronously with delay. It retries itself when an exception occurs, with a delay that increases every try.

```
@shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=None)
def cancel_issue_request(self):
    try:
         raise Exception('test')
     except Exception:
          countdown = 5 * 60 * (2 ** self.request.retries)

        raise self.retry(countdown=countdown, max_retries=5)
```

This works correctly in practice, but I'm trying to write a unit test that checks if the countdown has indeed the correct values.

What I've tried to do is mocking the cancel_issue_request.retry method, but once I do so the method itself breaks and doesn't retry the task.
I thought you could mock a method in such a way it still performs all its functionality with spec=celery.task.Task.retry, but I can't get it to work, please enlighten me?

Alternatively I'd like to read retries done from Celery somewhere, but I haven't been able to get that info out of Celery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to mock the function without breaking the functionality by doing:

```
cancel_issue_request.retry = Mock(side_effect=cancel_issue_request.retry)
```

Comment: should probably recommend using mock.patch.object like `with mock.patch.object(cancel_issue_request, 'retry', side_effect=cancel_issue_request.retry) as mocked_retry:`